# Is it correct to say "the problem of living cost increasing"?

Tags: british-english, formality

I'm curious about the right way to say the rising of living cost, because usually I will use:

1. The problem of living cost increasing
2. The living cost increasing problem
3. The increasing of living cost

but I have read some article, most of the authors are using "rising cost of living" instead of "living cost increasing".
Thus, can I know the right way to express the living cost is increasing (in formal writing)? Is it fine to say "the problem of living cost increasing"?

Comment: You can check different Google ngrams, but [these](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rising+cost+of+living%2Crising+living+cost&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crising%20cost%20of%20living%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crising%20living%20cost%3B%2Cc0) illustrate that "rising cost of living" is far more idiomatic (ie commonly used) than "rising living cost". It's not helpful to think 'but both seem equally grammatical'; English ...

Comment: is often idiosyncratic, and not going with the crowd marks you out as an outsider, and people will evaluate what you say accordingly. 1 - 3 above sound unnatural.

Comment: It needs to be "Living costs". Example: "The problem of living costs increasing"  I'd write an answer, but I don't really know the reason why it needs to be that way.  I just know as a native speaker that "living cost" without the "s" sounds very unnatural.